# MUL set the OF when it should not

Tags: assembly, x86, multiplication, x86-16

That's the problem: at the second `mul` the overflow flag gets set to 1; the multiplication is a simple `120*(-6) = -720`, which is contained in 16 bits... I don't understand why.

```
    .model small
    .stack 
    .data 
a dw 30    
b dw 3
c dw -6
ris dw ?       
    .code
    .startup 

mov ax, a
mov bx, 4
mul bx
jo ove

mov bx, c
mul bx
jo ove
```

...

```
    end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mul` is an *unsigned* multiply instruction, so you get an overflow because you are actually multiplying 120 * 65526. (Note that -6 signed = 0xfffa = 65526 unsigned.)

For *signed* multiplication you need `imul`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `IMUL` instead of `MUL` because of sign.